# Which is better: bibtex or biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

For a long time I used bibtex, but now with utf-8, it is recommended to use biblatex. Is biblatex better than bibtex? I am building a system that will use LaTeX. The system will use the bibliography style of the APA, among others. For that reason I would like to have solid foundations to argue the selection of one or the other.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This site encourages [specific questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) accompanied by a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).  Questions in the format of »What do you recommend?« are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: biblatex is a package, while bibtex is an application. So comparing both doesn't really work. But in my opinion the combination biblatex+biber is way better than any combination of a package like natbib or jurabib with bibtex. One argument is utf8 support which works natively with biber. The main argument against biblatex is that not every journal supports it.

Comment: You can have a look at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) for a few practical differences between the two. For proper APA style there are [`apacite`](https://ctan.org/pkg/apacite) for BibTeX and [`biblatex-apa`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) for `biblatex` (I can't vouch for the correctness of `apacite`, but I'm confident that `biblatex-apa` implements most APA requirements as far as possible). `apalike` does not offer full APA compliance.

Comment: Thanks, friends. I am novice in this. The [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib?noredirect=1&lq=1) solve the dude. Thanks!